# Pretty photo like functionality does not share the image as expected due to the #prettyphoto in the url

Tags: facebook-like, wordpress, prettyphoto

Facebook like does not work as expected with pretty photo.
Here is my url:
http://somedomain.com/photography/#!prettyPhoto[set_3]/0/ this url show an image in the pretty photo.

What i am seeing is that only till http://somedomain.com/photography/ is shared in the facebook, the link after the # is ignored.

Due to this issue all the images in the photography gallery shows the same like count.

How can i fix the issue?

Answer (score 0):

What does the developers.facebook.com/tools/debug tool say about the links you're trying to share?

An og:url meta tag or, canonical link meta tag, etc will redirect Facebook and may result in metadata being pulled from a page you weren't expecting it to be pulled from